# Split string in JavaScript and detect line break

Tags: javascript, string, canvas, split, line-breaks

I have a small function I found that takes a string from a `textarea` and then puts it into a `canvas` element and wraps the text when the line gets too long. But it doesn't detect line breaks. This is what it's doing and what it should do:

Input:

```
Hello

This is dummy text that could be inside the text area.
It will then get put into the canvas.
```

Wrong output:

```
Hello this is dummy text
that could be inside the
text area. It will then
get put into the canvas.
```

What it should output:

```
Hello

This is dummy text that
could be inside the text
area. It will then get
put into the canvas.
```

This is the function I'm using:

```
function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
    var words = text.split(' ');
    var line = '';

    for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
        var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
        var testWidth = metrics.width;
        if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
            context.fillText(line, x, y);
            line = words[n] + ' ';
            y += lineHeight;
        }
        else {
            line = testLine;
        }
    }
    context.fillText(line, x, y);
}
```

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to get? Or is there a way to simply move the text area as is into the canvas?

Comment: Line breaks created by automatic text-wrapping can't be detected. If a textarea contains line breaks created by hitting `ENTER`, they can be found for example by splitting with `\n`.

Comment: hmm, okay i'll have to re-strategise things. And theres no way to simply "move" a text area into a canvas?

Comment: You should put your solution into an answer and accept it, instead of putting it in the question.

Comment: Down-voted for accepting a jQuery answer for a JavaScript question. The web is full of people who have to `-jquery` *every* time we do a JavaScript search. ︎

Comment: @John: As Jean-Paul already told you, the answer includes both a non-jQuery solution and a jQuery solution.

Comment: @John this was asked 4 years ago at the height of jquery. And the answer can easily be converted between the two since the real take away was the '\n'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect line breaks in a text area input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950538/how-to-detect-line-breaks-in-a-text-area-input)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Using [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
var str = `your text
           that spans
           multiple lines`

// Split the string on \n or \r characters
var separateLines = str.split(/\r?\n|\r|\n/g);

alert("Total number of separate lines is: " + separateLines.length);
```

Or using [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead:

```js
var str = `your text
           that spans
           multiple lines`

// Split the string on \n or \r characters
var separateLines = str.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
 
alert("Total number of separate lines is: " + separateLines.length);
```

Comment: as a note: to get content of lines without newline char(s), we can use: `str.split(/\r?\n/g);` which works for `\r\n` and `\n`

Comment: @S.Serp Good addition.

Comment: Down-voted for answering **a JavaScript question with jQuery**. Dependencies are weaknesses and only slow the overall UX down.

Comment: @John Even though dependencies *can be* weaknesses, programming is always a trade-off between concise code and good performance. In this case, the question can be answered in two ways: using plain JavaScript and using jQuery. I gave the answers for both. It is up to the OP to decide which implementation to follow. Given that I show both approaches in my answer, your downvote seems unnecessary. But to each his own opinion.

Comment: @S.Serp `str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g)` if you also have `\r` only line breaks (like I )did

Comment: Seconding Jean-Paul's comment. If javascript is provided, a jquery alternative is acceptable. But it's worth noting that John has a point, even if a bit knee-jerk. There are plenty of circumstances where requiring jQuery is not ideal (or even not even possible).

Answer (score 53):

Split string in JavaScript

```
var array = str.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
```

OR

```
var array = str.split(/\r?\n/);
```

[image: Performance]

Comment: I suppose the second one is better for this purpose (splitting). Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, split faster

Comment: Is that a tool that is available online?

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to split a string from your JSON, the string has the \n special character replaced with \\n.

Split string by newline:

```
Result.split('\n');
```

Split string received in JSON, where special character **\n was replaced with \\n** during JSON.stringify(in javascript) or json.json_encode(in PHP). So, if you have your string in a AJAX response, it was processed for transportation. and if it is not decoded, it will sill have the \n replaced with \\n** and you need to use:

```
Result.split('\\n');
```

Note that the debugger tools from your browser might not show this aspect as you was expecting, but you can see that splitting by \\n resulted in 2 entries as I need in my case:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what I used to print text to a canvas. The input is not coming from a `textarea`, but from `input` and I'm only splitting by space. Definitely not perfect, but works for my case. It returns the lines in an array:

```
splitTextToLines: function (text) {
        var idealSplit = 7,
            maxSplit = 20,
            lineCounter = 0,
            lineIndex = 0,
            lines = [""],
            ch, i;

        for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            ch = text[i];
            if ((lineCounter >= idealSplit && ch === " ") || lineCounter >= maxSplit) {
                ch = "";
                lineCounter = -1;
                lineIndex++;
                lines.push("");
            }
            lines[lineIndex] += ch;
            lineCounter++;
        }

        return lines;
    }
```

Comment: Nice and simple solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split()` function to break input on the basis of line break.

```
yourString.split("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try detect the first line.

Then the:

```
if(n == 0){
  line = words[n]+"\n";
}
```

I'm not sure, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code I [OP] used. Probably not best practice, but it worked.

```
function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {

    var breaks = text.split('\n');
    var newLines = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < breaks.length; i ++){
      newLines = newLines + breaks[i] + ' breakLine ';
    }

    var words = newLines.split(' ');
    var line = '';
    console.log(words);
    for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
      if(words[n] != 'breakLine'){
        var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
        var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
        var testWidth = metrics.width;
        if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
          context.fillText(line, x, y);
          line = words[n] + ' ';
          y += lineHeight;
        }
        else {
          line = testLine;
        }
      }else{
          context.fillText(line, x, y);
          line = '';
          y += lineHeight;
      }
    }
    context.fillText(line, x, y);
  }
```