# JS turn a multi-line string into an array (each item= a line)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, multiline

For example, I have:

```
var str = "Hello
World"
```

I'm expecting an array like that : `array["Hello", "World"]`

I looked for a method that does that but nothing, I tried to make a loop but I don't know on what I should base my loop? From my knowledge there's not a .length property for the amount of lines in a string...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string in JavaScript and detect line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711768/split-string-in-javascript-and-detect-line-break)

Answer (score 3):

Use the split function:

```js
var str = `Hello
World`;
var splittedArray = str.split(/\r?\n/);
console.log(splittedArray)
```

Comment: This will throw a syntax error

Comment: Put a semicolon at the end of line 2

Comment: Still doesn't work. Semicolons are optional in javascript

Comment: Hello! It works fine, a huge thanks! The only problem is that it takes tab character "\t" as part of the string in the array item. I'm trying to remove it by using the .replace("\t", "") property but it's working only once by item in the array, for example the string is a div with html tags in it and I want to keep the tags as text (I used .text for that) but to remove "\t". Any ideas about that man? You're a life saver

Comment: @Konrad yeah I had an error at first but since the string I want to split is a div's content I don't have that syntax error, I guess this error comes from the fact that you can't manually just break to the line in JS code like that while declaring a variable.

Comment: @Konrad check again

Comment: @RedKitsun `.replace(/\t/g, "")`

Answer (score -1):

First thing is that the input string is not valid. It should be enclosed by [`backtick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) not with a quotes and then you can replace the new line break with the space and then split it to convert into an array.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var str = `Hello
World`;

const replacedStr = str.replace(/\n/g, " ")

console.log(replacedStr.split(' '));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function textArray(text) {
    const myArray = text.split("\n");
    return document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myArray
}

textArray(`line1
line2`)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from existing answers in a meaningful way? Please add an explanation to answers with code instead of plopping code in people's laps.