# Javascript to count number of texts within textarea by "enter"

Tags: javascript, text, textarea, enter

could you please inform how the number of texts can be counted within textarea by pressing "enter".

Textarea can be created like this:

```
 <textarea name="ta1" id="ta1" rows="4" cols="50">
 ABC[enter]
 DEF[enter]
 GHI[enter]
 </textarea>
 <input type="text" name="textnumber" value="">
```

Then "textnumber" will show "3" instantaneously. Thanks.

Comment: by `enter` you mean `newline`?

Comment: Yes, enter means newline

Comment: Hi, if you find some answer helpful and it solve your problem check it as correct answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try do that in this way

```
function getEntersCount(textarea, result) {
   var text = textarea.value,
       enters = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/),
       count = enters.length;

   result.value = count;
}

getEntersCount(
    document.getElementById("ta1"), 
    document.querySelector('[name="textnumber"]')
);
```

Guess this will help you

**EDIT 1**

```
getEntersCount(
    document.getElementById("ta1"), 
    document.getElementById('textnumber')
);
```

**EDIT 2**

```
// Function will take text and return count of lines in it
function getEntersCount(text) {
    var enters = text.split(/\r|\r\n|\n/),
        count = enters.length;       
    return count;
}

// Usage example
var count = getEntersCount(document.getElementById("ta1").value) 
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I used another javascript function to paste the "textnumber" value by using document.getElementById('textnumber').value, so I cannot trigger the function. But how?

Comment: Is it the approuch that you need?

Comment: Don`t forget to add  getEntersCount function in your code

Comment: Sorry, I say wrong previously. I used another javascript function to paste the "ta1" value by using document.getElementById('ta1').value (i.e. the value in multiple rows), so I cannot trigger the function. How do I trigger your function instead of using keyup or keydown?

Comment: I mean once the textarea has value, the function automatically works. Then how?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950538/how-to-detect-line-breaks-in-a-text-area-input)).

You can use Regex to find the number of newlines in a string.
The pattern to match is: `/\n/g` which means the number of occurances of a newline

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L6kqpbzm/).

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of newlines in the textarea you have to :

- get the value of textarea `var val = document.querySelector('textarea').value`
- then count `\n` (newline) `var res = val.match(/\n/g).length`

To bind the result and have it visualized in your input you can wrap this process in a function to be called on every textarea update,

try this:

```js
var tarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
var input = document.querySelector('input')

function update() {
  var res = (tarea.value.match(/\n/g)) ? tarea.value.match(/\n/g).length : 0;
  //                 ^^^^^^
  //          this is a ternary (like a conditional check)
  input.value = res;
}

tarea.addEventListener('input', update)
```

```html
<textarea name="ta1" id="ta1" rows="4" cols="50">
  ABC DEF GHI
</textarea>
<input type="text" name="textnumber" value="0">
```

Comment: Thanks. But can it be adjusted as: The original value of "textnumber" is 0. The value is updated only after pressing "enter".

Comment: you can just enter a starting `value="0"`

Comment: But when I tried to delete all contents in the textarea, the "textnumber" box returns to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: actually, if there were no newlines I was getting an error... I added a conditional check, in case no `\n` are found the value is `0`

Comment: Thank you. But I used another javascript function to paste the "textnumber" value by using document.getElementById('textnumber').value, so I cannot trigger the function. But how?